# DB connection close monitor

Tags: java, jdbc

I have the following use case.

Our client app will make an API(this is me) call which returns a java resultset after executing a db call to the client app. I would like to know when the clients are done using the  resultset so that I can close the resultset an the connection associated with it. So the design I thought was to send the resultset wrapped in an new object which has behaviors to close the resultset and the connection associated with it. This cleanup method has to be invoked by the client. Now, due to some reason if this cleanup method was never invoked by the client application, then we are going to endup with an open connection and un-freed DB resources. Is there a way to some how better monitor this and make sure all the DB resource are freed promptly. Additionally if there is any  design pattern that might help in this use case please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Never return an expensive DB resource like a `ResultSet` to outside the API where you lose all the control. Instead map it to a `List<Map<String, Object>>` or something reuseable and return it.

Comment: yeah, you are very right and thats how our API is written as of now. But our client app is so performance critical that they want to avoid the cost of creating another data structure from the resultset and instead want them directly.

Comment: If performance is so important, just make it a private API or create a new one wherein the `ResultSet` or other expensive DB resources is never exposed in public. I.e. bring the client app tighter to the DB without the need for a bunch of abstract layers.

Answer (score 1):

one way would be to clean up the resultset/connection from the object using phantom references (I would prefer that over using finalize) - this way, you should be able to clean up the object and simply return it to the pool.  Depending on your use case, you could look at timeouts as well.

Also, agreed with the other suggestion about not passing resultsets if possible.
hope it helps.

Comment: timeout is something i thought initially, but I dont want to take that chance as I dont know how much time the client app might need to hold on to the resultset. I will look try to explore phantom reference suggestion you made.